# Beginner confused about Python output /inner workings

Tags: python

I'm taking the "Python for Everyone" course. I recently got to database structures, and while I managed to successfully pass the assignment, it was due to stumbling upon the solution.

The assignment wanted a program to read through a text file of e-mail mailbox addresses, collect them all in a dictionary, and count up each occurrence, then print out the address with the highest occurrence, as well as the number of times it appeared. This is the program I wrote:

```
name = input("Enter file: ")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
sender = dict()
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        w = words[1]
        sender[w] = sender.get(w, 0) + 1
    else:
     continue
print(w, sender[w])
```

Originally I had the final `print` command indented one (which included it in the `for` loop). The output was that it gave me a complete list of every address, as well as the current tally next to it. I found that by moving the `print` command *out* of the loop, it returned the desired output.

Why does `w`, when moved out of the loop, return the desired email address, instead of giving me *all* of the email addresses (since it's `word[1]`)? Is it because it's part of the dictionary function to do so?

Comment: The value of *w* will be whatever was assigned to it in the **last** iteration of the loop. You will get a NameError exception if none of the lines in your file start with 'From '

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the for loop is reassigning a string to `w` on each iteration, so when you print `w` after the for loop you will only get the value that was most recently assigned to it. If you want to print all senders after the loop, you could do something like this:

```py
for s, c in sender.items():
    print(s, c)
```

Or if you want to output only the one(s) with the highest occurrence:

```py
maxcount = max(sender.values())
for s, c in sender.items():
    if c == maxcount:
        print(s, c)
```

Comment: Your code makes a lot of sense!  I was having difficulty understanding the max() function, and was worried that my solution was more luck than proper code.  I now see that it was.  Thank you for the explanation!